# Using cell value to set price in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a spreadsheet with a list of T-shirts and all of their varying sizes from Small to XL. I was just wondering if there is a way to create a formula that will set the price of the shirt in another row. I was messing around with formulas and the only one I could get to sort of work (for only ONE t-shirt size) was the following:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(K:K,"S"),25)
```

Is there a way to have multiple statements for the different sizes? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Your formula here will return 25 if at least one cell in the `K` column is equal to S (and `FALSE` otherwise). Please edit question to clarify exactly what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a 
"reference table" in a separate sheet and then do a vlookup.
So the table would look like below and then just do a vlookup to where all your shirts are at.

```
Size    | Price
XS      | 5
S       | 10
M       | 15
L       | 20
XL      | 5
```

Comment: Decent answer, although I would actually include the formula with `VLOOKUP` in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that worked perfectly. I created a reference table like you suggested and used the following VLOOKUP formula:

    =VLOOKUP(K:K,Prices,2,FALSE)

Comment: @Rob TIL that a VLOOKUP which uses a range as its first parameter will use the value from that range corresponding to the row in which the formula is placed.  (I had expected that formula to crash!)